# Is there a conventional term for the $e^{i\theta}$ thing in $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology, definition

In the polar representation of a complex number, is there a conventional term for the $e^{i\theta}$ thing in $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$? I know $|z|=\rho$ is typically called the *modulus*, and $\theta$ is typically called the *argument*.  $|z|\cos\theta=\Re z$ is called the *real part,* and $|z|\sin\theta=\Im z$ is called the *imaginary part.*  But I don't recall there being any standard term for the expression $e^{i\theta}$ as a whole.

Comment: I don't know of any such general term.  If $\mathbb{C}$ is thought of as a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, one *might* call that the "unit vector in the direction of $z$", or generate some language parallel to this (e.g. "the direction of $z$", perhaps).  But this would be purely idiosyncratic, so far as I know.

Comment: You could call it the "rotation", https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition

Comment: That corresponds nicely with my source which introduces the complex number along two parallel conceptual lines.  One being geometric, the other algebraic.  The geometric approach treats a complex number as a dilative rotation of the Euclidean plane about a fixed origin.  In that view, all complex numbers are fully characterized by the effect they have on the unit vector representing $1+0i$.

Answer (score 8):

It has a bit of physics ring to it, but, at least in a mixed company (mingling with physics majors) I often call it *the phase factor*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_factor) seems to give me some support.

Maybe I got used to it when working in telcomm? They do waves! I think I used it before my stint already :-)

Answer (score 2):

From linear algebra, I think it would be reasonable to call that factor the "direction", but I don't think that's common when working with the complex plane like this.

Comment: That's what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

This is often referred to as cis (for cosine plus i sine) See [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cis.html), for example. Thus,

$$
\text{cis}(\theta)=e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta
$$

Beyond that, $e^{i\theta}$ is literally an anticlockwise rotation of $\theta$ radians.